# Determining if Django is caching my HTML Content

Tags: html, django

I'm using Django==2.2.6 (haven't kept up with the later releases, I don't know what's new) and it seems like it is caching my html-files, somehow?

Currently, at the index-page is says:

```
<h1>SHISH</h1>
```

There are NO references to "SHISH" in the code, whatsoever.

This is the TEMPLATES-setting.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'website.context_processors.check_user_settings',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

I run the local server using: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80

This is index.html

```
{% extends 'website/base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap i18n %}

{% block content %}
    {% if USER_HAS_MISSING_PROFILE_DATA %}
        <a href="{% url "user_settings" %}">{% trans "Please update your profile" %}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is the Viev:

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "core/index.html"
```

Comment: If you don't show the view for the index page and the template for it, there's no way we can help. I don't see how the `TEMPLATES` setting would be useful.

Comment: There's no caching unless you enable it yourself. But why are you suspecting caching in the first place? Do you have another project with "SHISH"? Are you sure you're running `manage.py runserver` in the correct environment and correct directory?

Comment: I'm positive that I'm running runserver in the correct envorinment and directory. I've updated the question. Thanks for the help. I'm confused at the moment.

Comment: It started working when I exit the environment and entered it again. A *lot* of code had not been updated. It started crasching on a context-processor instead. I've fixed that one and the HTML is now correct.

Comment: So this is not an issue anymore?

Comment: Nope. And I'm not sure how I solved it. Probably waited it out. ;)